# Value from textbox gets blank after update

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I have this edit link (name) where the value from the database gets transformed to textbox when clicked. The problem is when I update other normal textbox (age), the value from the edit link textbox becomes blank. But when I input a value into the edit link textbox, the value is saved. Why is it that everytime I update other textbox, the edit link textbox value becomes blank? Please help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.edit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
        var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
        dad.find('label').hide();
        dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().focus();
  return false;
    });
 
 $(".edit-input").focusout(function() {
        var dad = $(this).parent();
        $(this).hide();
        dad.find('label').show();
  
    });
```

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM details"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($rowwaf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo "<td><label for=\ "name\" class=\ "control-label\">
      <p class=\"text-info\" style=\"color: black\">".$rowwaf["name"]."</p></label>
      <input type=\ "text\" class=\ "edit-input\" name=\ "name\" placeholder=\ " ".$rowwaf[ "name"]. " \" maxlength=\ "10\" />
      <div class=\ "controls\">
       <a class=\ "edit\" href=\ "#\">Edit</a>
      </div>
echo "<td ><input size=\"18\" type=\"text\" name=\"age\" value=\"".$rowwaf["age"]."\"></td>\n" ;
</td>";
```

My update query:

```js
$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$id = $_POST["id"];

 $updquery = "UPDATE details
 SET name = '$name', age = '$age'
 WHERE id = '$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$updquery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with the `echo` statement from `php`.

```
<input type="text" class="edit-input" name="name" placeholder="$rowwaf["name"]" value="$rowwaf["name"]" maxlength="10" />
```

You are setting `placeholder`, I guess you also need to set the `value` attribute to the input tag.

If it doesn't help, try including a running snippet. Maybe we could do something about it then!